# Count number of subsequences of A such that every element of the subsequence is divisible by its index (starts from 1)

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

B is a subsequence of A if and only if we can turn A to B by removing zero or more element(s).

```
A = [1,2,3,4]
B = [1,4] is a subsequence of A.(Just remove 2 and 4).
B = [4,1] is not a subsequence of A.
```

Count all subsequences of A that satisfy this condition : `A[i]%i = 0`

Note that `i` **starts from 1** not 0.

Example :

```
Input : 
5
2 2 1 22 14
Output:
13
```

All of these 13 subsequences satisfy B[i]%i = 0 condition.

{2},{2,2},{2,22},{2,14},{2},{2,22},{2,14},{1},{1,22},{1,14},{22},{22,14},{14}

My attempt :

The only solution that I could came up with has `O(n^2)` complexity.

Comment: But do you need to list them all or just output the number?

Comment: Just return the count.

Comment: I think you can count the indices where A[i]%i = 0 and then just use the formula for counting the combinations

Comment: (Step 1) For every number, find all divisor no greater than the length of A. Let the total number of divisors be K. (Step 2) It's easy to modify the O(n^2) DP to O(K). (Too long to fit in a comment.)

Comment: Where is this from? What are the limits? Can we submit solutions for testing somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the maximum element in `A` is `C`, the following is an algorithm with time complexity `O(n * sqrt(C))`:

1. For every element `x` in `A`, find all divisors of `x`.
2. For every `i` from 1 to `n`, find every `j` such that `A[j]` is a multiple of `i`, using the result of step 1.
3. For every `i` from 1 to `n` and `j` such that `A[j]` is a multiple of `i` (using the result of step 2), find the number of `B` that has `i` elements and the last element is `A[j]` (dynamic programming).

```py
def find_factors(x):
    """Returns all factors of x"""
    for i in range(1, int(x ** 0.5) + 1):
        if x % i == 0:
            yield i
            if i != x // i:
                yield x // i

def solve(a):
    """Returns the answer for a"""
    n = len(a)

    # b[i] contains every j such that a[j] is a multiple of i+1.
    b = [[] for i in range(n)]
    for i, x in enumerate(a):
        for factor in find_factors(x):
            if factor <= n:
                b[factor - 1].append(i)

    # There are dp[i][j] sub arrays of A of length (i+1) ending at b[i][j]
    dp = [[] for i in range(n)]
    dp[0] = [1] * n
    for i in range(1, n):
        k = x = 0
        for j in b[i]:
            while k < len(b[i - 1]) and b[i - 1][k] < j:
                x += dp[i - 1][k]
                k += 1
            dp[i].append(x)

    return sum(sum(dpi) for dpi in dp)
```

Comment: (Voted up) I think mine is similar but maybe uses less space?

Answer (score 2):

For every divisor `d` of `A[i]`, where `d` is greater than 1 and at most `i+1`, `A[i]` can be the `d`th element of the number of subsequences already counted for `d-1`.

JavaScript code:

```js
function getDivisors(n, max){
  let m = 1;
  const left = [];
  const right = [];
  
  while (m*m <= n && m <= max){
    if (n % m == 0){
      left.push(m);
      
      const l = n / m;
      
      if (l != m && l <= max)
        right.push(l);
    }
      
    m += 1;
  }
  
  return right.concat(left.reverse());
}


function f(A){
  const dp = [1, ...new Array(A.length).fill(0)];
  
  let result = 0;
  
  for (let i=0; i<A.length; i++){
    for (d of getDivisors(A[i], i+1)){
      result += dp[d-1];
      dp[d] += dp[d-1];
    }
  }
  
  return result;
}


var A = [2, 2, 1, 22, 14];
console.log(JSON.stringify(A));
console.log(f(A));
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that for the general case we can't provably find an algorithm with complexity less than `O(n^2)`.

First, an intuitive explanation:

Let's indicate the elements of the array by `a1, a2, a3, ..., a_n`.

If the element `a1` appears in a subarray, it must be element no. 1.

If the element `a2` appears in a subarray, it can be element no. 1 or 2.

If the element `a3` appears in a subarray, it can be element no. 1, 2 or 3.

...

If the element `a_n` appears in a subarray, it can be element no. 1, 2, 3, ..., n.

So to take all the possibilities into account, we have to perform the following tests:

Check if `a1` is divisible by 1 (trivial, of course)

Check if `a2` is divisible by 1 or 2

Check if `a3` is divisible by 1, 2 or 3

...

Check if `a_n` is divisible by 1, 2, 3, ..., n

All in all we have to perform `1+ 2 + 3 + ... + n = n(n - 1) / 2` tests, which gives a complexity of O(n^2).

Note that the above is somewhat inaccurate, because not all the tests are strictly necessary. For example, if `a_i` is divisible by 2 and 3 then it must be divisible by 6. Nevertheless, I think this gives a good intuition.

Now for a more formal argument:

Define an array like so:

`a1 = 1`

`a2 = 1× 2`

`a3 = 1× 2 × 3`

...

`a_n = 1 × 2 × 3 × ... × n`

By the definition, every subarray is valid.

Now let `(m, p)` be such that `m <= n` and `p <= n and change` a_m`to`a_m / p`. We can now choose one of two paths:

1. If we restrict `p` to be prime, then each tuple `(m, p)` represents a mandatory test, because the corresponding change in the value of `a_m` changes the number of valid subarrays. But that requires prime  factorization of each number between 1 and `n`. By the known methods, I don't think we can get here a complexity less than `O(n^2)`.
2. If we omit the above restriction, then we clearly perform `n(n - 1) / 2` tests, which gives a complexity of `O(n^2)`.

Comment: Sure we can. Mine is `O(n * sqrt(max(A)))`, where `A` is the input array.

Comment: @גלעדברקן That's not O(n^2) when max(A)=ω(n^2).

Comment: @גלעדברקן I did say when max(A)=ω(n^2).

Comment: @גלעדברקן While your algorithm is O(n^2) (assuming O(1) arithmetic), "n * sqrt(max(A))" is NOT O(n^2) when max(A)=ω(n^2). For example, if max(A) = ϴ(n^4), "n * sqrt(max(A))" would be ϴ(n^3).

Comment: I think what @johnchen002 is trying to say is that `O(n×sqrt(max(A))` is not better nor worse than `O(n^2)`, the two complexity terms are just incomparable since they are expressed using different parameters. `max(A)` may tend to infinity just as fast as `n`, or faster or slower, we just don't know.

Comment: @johnchen002 ah, I see. Is that the difference between "big O" and "small o?" Nonetheless, my claim that we can do better stands. But it does include a condition on max(A) :)